# C# Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, palindrome, console.writeline

So, I wrote this code to run string values in a json file and determine if it is a palindrome or not. I am having trouble displaying the results in the console correctly. My Console.WriteLine is the issue (i think). It displays the true/false answers, but I need the actual string to appear with it. For example: "mom: true'. Meaning it is a palindrome. Any tips?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
    {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     //receive json from url
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        WebClient n = new WebClient();
        var json = n.DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bungard/PalindromeTest/master/string.json");
        string valueOriginal = Convert.ToString(json);

        //parse
        Root palindromes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
        foreach (Palindromes pals in palindromes.Strings)
        {

          Console.WriteLine(pals.result = IsPalindrome(pals.str).ToString());**
        }


    }
    public class Root
    {
        public List<Palindromes> Strings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Palindromes
    {
        public string str { get; set; }
        public string result { get; set; }
    }



    public static bool IsPalindrome(string value)
    {
        char[] forwards = (from c in value.ToLower().ToCharArray() where char.IsLetter(c) select c).ToArray();
        int middle = (forwards.Length / 2) + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
            if (forwards[i] != forwards[forwards.Length - 1 - i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString(json)` is _**not**_ doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with this:

```
pals.result = IsPalindrome(pals.str).ToString();
Console.WriteLine($"{pals.str}: {pals.result}");
```

Comment: Did not work. I have 5 separate strings. Mom is the first one. My code displays 5 lines: all the true or false answers. I just need the string to appear next to the answer

Comment: @idkidk see my edited answer it I understood you correctly

Comment: Thanks, it does not recognize the $ though

Comment: @idkidk seems like you are using old VS, you can use this syntax: `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", pals.str, pals.result));`